# Accessing HashMap being used as a Cache

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap, thread-safety

I have a rest api which inserts a record into database with an id say entityId. I have a HashMap which saves the entityId and the entity object and it is acting here as a cache.

Just After inserting the entity and updating the cache(HashMap) when I do a look up it is sometime not able to find the id from the cache.

Note :- I am running the rest api in a loop and doing a load testing to verify the object is always present in the cache

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated. What can be the reason that is not able to find the id from the cache.

Comment: is it ConcurrentHashMap? What is the scope of class? Are you doing logging after updating cache? If yes can you see the id?

Comment: Yes when I do a logging I see that the latest values is present in the map. But I try to fetch the value using ma.getValues() method the newly added value is not reflecting.

Comment: And when I do a second look up from the same map I can see that the value is present most of the times.

Comment: I have tried using both HashMap and ConcurrentHashMap

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your load testing is being run and the time interval between subsequent write and read requests.

Although what is more important is the way your Cache/Hashmap is being updated.

```
Are you updating the HashMap BEFORE inserting into the Database


Are you updating the HashMap AFTER inserting into the Database.
```

If your doing the insert after writing into the Database, then there will potentially be a lag before the HashMap gets updated, which means that when the subsequent request for the read comes in the HashMap has not been updated as yet.

It might be worth adding in a log at the point the Request is being added into the HM, and a log for the time the Read request is coming in. That might give you some idea about whether the HashMap has actually been updated or not.

Comment: Why there will be a lag when the HashMap is getting updated after inserting into database ?

Comment: It depends on how long it takes for inserting a record into the database, and how your connections have been setup to the Database. But if you make the update to the HashMap after Database insertion it could mean a few hundred milliseconds before the HashMap gets updated. And since you mentioned you were doing this in a loop, it could potentially mean that your REST API for the read is triggered even before this update. Again I am not saying this could be the issue, all I am suggesting is it could be a potential cause for it.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is not threadsafe, see [the API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more mappings; merely changing the value associated with a key that an instance already contains is not a structural modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the map. If no such object exists, the map should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedMap method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to the map:

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap(...));
```

The inserts into the map that you're describing would count as a structural modifications.

Use a [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) instead, updates don't lock the whole data structure the way the above code with the `synchronizedMap` will.

If the problem is that the new value doesn't make it into the cache before other threads need to use it, just because the threads are accessing the same code in quick succession, it may be better to live with the cache misses than to introduce a bottleneck. It may be better to not cache the result on insert but wait for the first select query (in a new transaction after the insert has been committed), so you avoid the case where you add an entry to your cache and then the transaction rolls back, leaving you with invalid data in the cache.

Also there is a danger of using a lot of memory storing entries that don't get used. You could have a worker thread periodically check for expired items.

Caching is one of those things that is harder than it looks. Consider using [ehcache](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/integrations/jdbc.html) as an alternative to rolling your own solution here.